# Ng-checked not updating after data is being modified

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-checked

i have the following problem with the ng-checked component : i have a list of entries with a checked property that is passed in the html template. Initially the entries come with false on checked but after processing some data the value is set to true. Although i modify the array and i have a watch set on that directive the checked value is not updated(is set to false). I don't know what am i missing.
Template :

```
<span data-ng-repeat="item in data_used track by $index" ng-class="class">
        <input id="{{name_used}}_{{item.value}}" 
               type="checkbox" 
               name="{{name_used}}" 
               value="{{item.value}}" 
               data-ng-click="checkbox_click(item, $event)" 
               data-ng-checked="{{item.checked}}" 
               tabindex="0"/>
        <label for="{{name_used}}_{{item.value}}" 
               data-ng-show="item.text">{{item.text}}
        </label>
    </span>
```

Controller :

```
$scope.$watch('data', function() {  
                    var array = angular.fromJson($scope.data);
                });
```

Array passed to the directive :

```
$scope.useForAccountData = [
  {
   text: lang.get('nli_customer_data_debit_placeholder'),
   value: 'debit',
   backendValue: 'refund',
   checked: false
  },
  {
   text: lang.get('nli_customer_data_credit_placeholder'),
   value: 'credit',
   backendValue: 'withdrawal',
  checked: false
  }
];
```

The part where the array is update :

```
angular.forEach($scope.useForAccountData,function(el) { 
    if(bankAccount.usedFor && bankAccount.usedFor.indexOf(el.backendValue) >= 0) {
      el.checked = true;
    }
});
```

Whole directive :

```
'use strict';

define(['angular'], function(angular) {


return angular.module('portals.vio.checkboxGroup', [])
    /* Directive */
    .directive('vioCheckboxGroup', [
    function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'AE',
            scope: {
                disabled: '@',
                click: '&',
                reset: '=?',
                data: '@',
                dataAddress: '@',
                name: '@',
                fieldsetLegend: '@',
                dynamic: '@',
                class: '@',
                validationRules: '=',
                validate: '='
            },
            controller: ['$scope','$http', 'lang', 'validationUtils', function($scope,$http,lang,validationUtils) {
                if( $scope.validationRules &&
                        $scope.validationRules.helperMessage) {
                        //show the helper message
                        $scope.textShow = 'help';
                        $scope.validationText = $scope.validationRules.helperMessage;
                    }
                $scope.itemsChecked = [];
                $scope.itemsCheckedPositions = [];
                if($scope.dataAddress) {
                    $http.get($scope.dataAddress).then(function(resp) {
                        $scope.data_used = angular.fromJson(resp.data);                                                                   
                    }, function(err) {
                        $scope.data_used = angular.fromJson($scope.data);
                    });   
                }
                else if($scope.data) {
                    $scope.data_used = angular.fromJson($scope.data);
                }
                $scope.name_used = ($scope.name) ? $scope.name: 'default';

                /* Trigger the given callback everytime a checkbox is toggled */
                $scope.checkbox_click = function(item, event) {
                    if(item.checked)
                        item.checked = false;
                    else
                        item.checked = true;


                    /* Create a list with all checked checkboxes */
                    angular.forEach($scope.data_used, function(val, key) {
                        if(val.checked){
                            $scope.itemsChecked.push(val);
                            $scope.itemsCheckedPositions.push(key);
                        }
                    });

                    var valid = $scope.validateCheckbox();

                    $scope.click({items: $scope.itemsChecked, valid: valid});
                };
                $scope.$watch('data', function() {  
                    var array = angular.fromJson($scope.data);
                });

                /* Function triggered through the reset callback */
                $scope.reset_fields = function() {
                    angular.forEach($scope.data_used, function(val, key) {
                        val.checked = false;
                    });
                };

                $scope.reset = function() {
                    $scope.reset_fields();
                };
                if( $scope.validationRules) {
                    $scope.validate = function(obj) {
                        if(obj === undefined) {
                            if(!$scope.valid) {
                                $scope.validateCheckbox();
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            if( obj.type && obj.message) {
                                $scope.textShow = obj.type; 
                                $scope.validationText = obj.message;
                            }
                        } 
                    };
                };

                $scope.validateCheckbox = function() {
                    var checkboxIsValid = true;
                    if( $scope.validationRules && 
                        $scope.validationRules.hasChecked) {

                        try {
                            if($scope.itemsChecked.length !== $scope.validationRules.hasChecked ) {
                                $scope.textShow = 'error'; 
                                $scope.validationText = lang.get('errorSelectionNotMatchingSetNumber') + $scope.validationRules.hasChecked + lang.get('elements');
                                checkboxIsValid = false;
                            }
                        }
                        catch(ex) {
                            checkboxIsValid = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if( $scope.validationRules && 
                        $scope.validationRules.hasCheckedAtLeast) {

                        try {
                            if($scope.itemsChecked.length < $scope.validationRules.hasCheckedAtLeast) {
                                $scope.textShow = 'error'; 
                                $scope.validationText = lang.get('errorSelectionLowerThanExpected') + $scope.validationRules.hasCheckedAtLeast + lang.get('elements');
                                checkboxIsValid = false;
                            }
                        }
                        catch(ex) {
                            checkboxIsValid = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if( $scope.validationRules &&
                        $scope.validationRules.hasItemsChecked) {

                        try {
                            var counter = 0;
                            angular.forEach($scope.itemsCheckedPositions, function(val,key){
                                if($scope.itemsCheckedPositions.indexOf(val)<0){
                                    counter++;
                                }
                            });
                            if(counter !== $scope.itemsCheckedPositions.length) {
                                $scope.textShow = 'error'; 
                                $scope.validationText = lang.get('errorSelectionDifferentThanPresetOnes');
                                checkboxIsValid = false;
                            }

                        }
                        catch(ex) {
                            checkboxIsValid = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if(checkboxIsValid) {
                        $scope.textShow = ''; 
                        $scope.validationText = '';
                    }

                    return checkboxIsValid;                     

                }; 

                validationUtils.registerValidationEvents($scope, $scope.validateCheckbox);

            }],
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: '../../ui.components.base/vio-checkbox-group/vio-checkbox-group.html',
            link: function($scope, elem, attrs) {

                /* Update the fieldset legend with a name, if given */
                $scope.$watch('fieldsetLegend', function(new_val, old_val) {

                    var legend_elem = elem.find('legend');
                    legend_elem.remove();

                    if(new_val !== undefined) {
                        elem.find('fieldset')
                            .prepend('<legend>' + new_val + '</legend>');
                    }
                });



            }
        };
    }]);
```

});

After updating the array in the watch part i see the values with checked true but in the html the ng-checked property is still false.

Thanks,
Vio

Comment: Can you show the directive?

Comment: I updated my question with the whole directive

Comment: Btw, please format your code. It's much easier to read code with proper indentation. As a tip you have a preview beneath your edit window, so you can see the code before posting or saving your question.